# How to add single quotes in a shell script using sed

Tags: string, bash, shell, sed

Need help in making a sed script to find and replace user input along with single quotes.  Input file *admins.py*:

Script:

```
                       read adminsid
                       while [[ $adminsid == "" ]];
                               do
                               echo "You did not enter anything. Please re-enter AdminID"
                               read adminsid 
                               done

## Please enter Admin's ID
9999999999,8888888888,1111111111

## Script To Replace ADMIN_IDS = [] to ADMIN_IDS = ['9999999999,8888888888,1111111111'] in file
   sed -i "s|ADMIN_IDS = \[.*\]|ADMIN_IDS = ['$adminsid']|g" $file

## Current results:

   ADMIN_IDS = ['9999999999,8888888888,1111111111']

## Expected results:

   ADMIN_IDS = ['9999999999','8888888888','1111111111']
```

Comment: Please read about [SE's code quoting syntax](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).

Answer (score 1):

Assign the variable to the data

```
adminsid=9999999999,8888888888,1111111111
```

Then use `sed -e` (script) option to add the quoting, and square brackets.

```
echo "$adminsid" | sed -e "s/,/\',\'/g" -e "s/^/[\'/" -e "s/$/\']/"
```

or to apply changes to a file (filename in `$file`):

```
sed -i "$file" -e "s/,/\',\'/g" -e "s/^/[\'/" -e "s/$/\']/"
```

Comment: Added variant for text changes stored in a file :)

Comment: Hi, this string `sed -i "$file" -e "s/,/\',\'/g" -e "s/^/[\'/" -e "s/$/\']/"` replaces all the lines in the file. I would like to replace only lines that contains [] brackets

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `awk` too:

Suppose you have assigned the variable as :

```
adminsid=9999999999,8888888888,1111111111
```

Then the solution:

```
echo "$adminsid"| awk -F"," -v quote="'" -v OFS="','" '$1=$1 {print "["quote $0 quote"]"}'
```

1. `-F"," -v OFS="','"` :: Replacing separator (,) with (',')
2. `print "["quote $0 quote"]"` :: Add single quotes(') and ([) and (]) to the begin and end of line

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed & bash):

```
<<<"$adminsid" sed 's/[^,]\+/'\''&'\''/g;s/.*/[&]/'
```

Surround all non-comma characters by single quotes and then surround the entire string by square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `,` with `','` in the variable and add characters at the beginning and at the end.

```
sed "s/.*/['&']/" <<< "${adminsid//,/','}"
```

Answer (score 0):

```sh
echo "('${adminsid//,/\\',\\'}')"
```

Comment: `echo "['${adminsid//,/','}']"`

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing and why you believe it is the best approach?